# Set-builder notation: is there another symbol for "such that"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

My teacher is teaching us about sets, and he said that the '|', the ':' and the '\' symbols can be used to mean 'such that'. I'm certain of the first two, but I searched a little and couldn't find reference to the last. Does it exist for this purpose? If it's a special character, what Unicode code point does it have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never seen it used that way, and I've read a fair amount of obscure historical material about set theory that uses obsolete notation.

Comment: I've never seen something like '\' used for that purpose.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I guess the OP meant “/”.

Comment: @PseudoNeo While writing by hand, sombody writes $/$ instead of $\mid$ to denote the vertical bar. Probably because it is easier to write :-)

Comment: @Siminore: Twas my point ;-) I also know of people who use “/” even when typesetting.

Comment: I have seen "/" used first time in my life very recently.

Comment: I first saw this use of ‘/’ here; I find it rather disconcerting.

Comment: @PseudoNeo: I actually meant '\', as in backslash.

Comment: Thanks for all of the answers, but the one that better reassured me was @Mark Dominus'. I'm terrified of teachers that present us with their own version of things and make it look like they're standard. This was not the case though. It was more like "this symbol is also used". Perhaps he meant a '|' that got inclined when written, instead of the '\' character. Which is contradictory, since things get inclined to the other side in handwriting. Go figure. Glad I got this one clear: either ':' or '|' are the most common.

Comment: I didn't want to post it as an answer because there's a lot of stuff I haven't seen that nevertheless exists.

Comment: I use a semicolon, like so: $\{x ∈ X;\; φ(x)\}$. A professor of mine did so and I adapted this as well because it looks good and the semicolon is almost never used in any other way (as opposed to “$|$” or “$:$”).

Answer (score 7):

We usually use ":" and "|", as in $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0\}$. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Those wondering how to read this expression is *The set of all real numbers $x$ such that $x$ is greater than $0$* To read such *set builder* notation took my some valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

I had a professor use a backwards "element of ($\in$) " sign to stand for "such that".  He's the only one I've seen do it, and it very well could be unique to him.  But there are probably many people with their own unique, preferred symbols.  I wasn't a fan of it, so I stick to the basic ":" and "|", depending on how many other vertical lines are in the set description.

Comment: As far as I know, the "correct" symbol should be $\ni'$: the formula $(\exists x) \ni' (x>0)$ is sometimes read "there is an $x$ such that $x>0$.

Comment: But surely he didn't write it as $\{ x\in X \ni \varphi(x)\}$? That would be extremely confusing.

Comment: I also have seen the backwards element sign used. I used it in an assignment sometime thereafter, and got lots of comments from the grader saying "what the heck does this mean???"

Comment: I have seen it used and have used it myself. But now I prefer just "s.t." in sentences and the vertical bar in set-forming brackets.

Comment: Read also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15455/backwards-epsilon

Comment: Apart from the use as given above in the definition of a set, I am against replacing words such as "such that" by symbols. But I not a logician!

Comment: I’ve been familiar with $\owns$ for *such that* for decades, but it’s not common, and I don’t recommend it. If I’m writing at the board, with space and and time at a premium, I prefer *s.t.* For sets I much prefer the colon.

Comment: what is the latex for the backwards element of?

Comment: @Francis $\ni $ is \ni , as in \in backwards. You can also right-click any formula here and have it shown as LaTeX.

Comment: For abbreviating *such that*, I have a professor who likes to use the dollar sign $\$$. He says it looks like the letters s and t superimposed. I actually got used to it really quickly.