# What does the symbol described below mean? (looks like: sideway u with a line through the middle)

Tags: notation

The symbol kind of looks like this: ε, but it's more like a sideways u with a line through the middle.

Comment: Perhaps [set membership.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_%28mathematics%29) Sea also Wikipedia's [list of math symbols.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) The notation dates back to Peano according to Jeff Miller's [Earliest Uses of Symbols of Set Theory and Logic:](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) Giuseppe Peano (1858-1932) used an epsilon for membership in Arithmetices prinicipia nova methodo exposita, Turin 1889 (page vi, x). He stated that the symbol was an abbreviation for *est;* the entire work is in Latin.

Comment: Peano also used a backwards epsilon for "such that" in 1898, see [this prior question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/15460/242)

Comment: sideways u ... pointing which direction?  Line through the middle:  vertical, horizontal, diagonal?

Comment: @BillDubuque I know Peano came up with $\forall$, $\exists$, $\nexists$, etc. but I did not know he also invented $\ni$ for "such that".

Comment: No set membership is $\in$, not $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Surely $\in$ is one possible interpretation of the OP's description "looks like this: ε, but it's more like a sideways u with a line through the middle."

Comment: I am just looking at the symbol in front of me and giving the most plausible answer, the absence of any context.

Comment: Okay, cool down here...it's just a symbol :-)

Comment: @glebovg I am not sure where I learned that ∋ meant "such that", but I do remember learning that is is non-standard/uncommon, when I used it in an assignment and the grader had no idea what I was writing :)

Comment: Jessica asked the question, then it seems she never came back to see the answers.

Comment: @EdGorcenski I found [this](http://math.umaine.edu/~farlow/sec13.pdf), where Prof. Farlow mentions $\ni $. I usually use $:$ to denote "such that". It makes more sense.

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean $\in$? This means "an element of". For example, if we denote the set of natural numbers by ${\mathbb N}$ then $1 \in {\mathbb N}$. Similarly, $1,2,3, \ldots  \in {\mathbb N}$, and $ - 1 \notin {\mathbb N}$. Sometimes you might also see $\ni$, which some authors use for "such that". You might also be referring to $\epsilon$, which is the same as $\varepsilon $, or perhaps you mean $\not\subset$, which usually means "not a subset of".

Comment: Interestingly, I've seen $\ni$ where the an element of a set is to the right of the set, like $\supset$ is used for set membership.

Comment: You can use $a \in X$ or $X \ni a$, they mean the same (at least to all the books I've seen this in. But of course it's always better to just mention what you mean by a notation before using it.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I have not seen people use $\ni$ for membership. It makes more sense to use $\in$ because it looks like the letter e for element. It also looks like $\epsilon$, again epsilon (the first letter is e) for element.

Comment: Actually I never see people using $\epsilon$ to denote membership. I know that the symbol $\in$ is essentially an epsilon but I reserve $\varepsilon$ for numbers and $\in$ for membership, this thing $\epsilon$, I hate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Greek letter $\epsilon$, but the font is a little different like this $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Greeks have fonts, too.

Comment: @Jennifer It's called epsilon: $\epsilon$, which can be formatted on this site using `$\epsilon$`

Comment: Its variant is `\varepsilon`.