# "such that" logical symbol

Tags: notation

So, in the definition of what is a square root,

> $\sqrt{x}$ are all numbers $y$ such that $y×y=x$.

are there any logical mathematical symbols so that the above definition can be written using logical operators only, and no natural language?

Where can I get some introductory or reference material on all such logical symbols?

**update**:
I noticed, some time after asking the question that the definition of square root I am giving is wrong. The square root of $x$ is to defined to be the non-negative number $y$ that satisfies $y*y=x$. But the question was about notation, not square roots, so I am leaving it as it stands due to some answers using the supplied (erroneous) definition.

Comment: In set theory \mid or : is often used but I haven't really seen any logical symbol used for "such that" in other situations. But now that I think of it there is the \ni symbol used as "such that" in mathematical logic I believe.

Comment: I used to sometimes see a backwards $\in$ symbol or something like it for "such that."

Comment: @Andrews I thought the reverse Greek epsilon was for 'exists'

Comment: "Exists" is usually a reversed (Roman) E:  $\exists$

Comment: Marcus, $\in$ came from the letter $\varepsilon$, so $\ni$ is sort of a descendant of backwards epsilon.

Comment: I had a professor who used $\ni$ frequently. He wrote it quickly or in a stylized manner, and I never knew what the symbol actually was. He also wrote "suppose" as a sort of uppercase $S$ with a lowercase $p$ superimposed on the bottom half. Detexify couldn't find that one for me. Anyone seen that?

Comment: The term you are looking for is "set comprehension".

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309506/symbol-for-such-that-not-in-set/2777911#2777911 My answer is in this link. Personally, I would prefer **s.t.**, ${\ni}'$, or $\stackrel{\bullet}{\equiv}$. Others could mean other things in maths, but not these I don't think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbol for “such that” (not in set)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309506/symbol-for-such-that-not-in-set)

Comment: Colon or st.   What is the logic of st, is it just AND?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could write this in a few different ways... I'm not sure what you're asking, so let me show you a couple.

For one, you could define the condition $y\in\text{Sqrt}(x)$, rather than the set itself:
$$
y\in\text{Sqrt}(x)\Leftrightarrow y^2=x
$$

The following two are commonly used in set definitions:
$$
\text{Sqrt}(x)=\{y\mid y^2=x\}\qquad \text{or}\qquad \text{Sqrt}(x)=\{y:\ y^2=x\}
$$

I also see people use (and have used myself) "s.t." as an abbreviation for such that in formulas.

Comment: I hate the ambiguity of the set notation. Though extremely unlikely, $\text{Sqrt}(x)=\{y\mid y^2=x\}$ can mean that the statement $y\mid y^2$ is the only element of the set $\text{Sqrt}(x)$, where in the same context we have that $x=y^2$, and $\text{Sqrt}(x)=\{y:\  y^2=x\}$ can mean that $\text{Sqrt}(x)$ is a set containing only the statement $\frac{1}{y}=x$.

Comment: in all my years in methematics i never saw that "ambiguity". in latex, \mid is even a different symbol than | for "divides".

Comment: @peter I agree, and $:$ can get confusing when dealing with ratios. Look at my comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, there doesn't need to be a symbol other than a colon or $\mid$ for "such that."

The English language version of your statement seems to describe $\sqrt x$ as a set. You could write this as:

$$y\in \sqrt{x} \iff y\in\mathbb R \land y\cdot y = x$$

Note, I've added the $y\in\mathbb R$ because you need to know the domain in which you are working. You could chaange that, of course.

This is often abbreviated as:

$$\sqrt{x} =\{y\in\mathbb R\mid y\cdot y = x\}$$

Roughly, the $\mid$ character functions as a "such that" symbol here. Sometimes a $:$ symbol is used instead.

Answer (score 4):

I think I remember that I have seen notations such as
$$ \sqrt x :=\iota y (y\ge 0\land y^2=x)$$
i.e. $\iota v \Phi$ is used to denote the unique element of the (hopefully) singleton set $\{v\mid \Phi\}$. While having such a notation may be useful for extreme formality, I am personally no friend of it.

Comment: Yeah I think I made a mistake in the question in that the square root should be defined as a single number (the "principal square root"), and not as a set, so I think from a strict mathematical perspective your answer is the correct one.

Comment: That $\iota$ notation is from Whitehead and Russell's *Principia Mathematica*.

Comment: cf. http://planetmath.org/hilbertsvarepsilonoperator

Answer (score -5):

I ALSO have seen a backwards ∈ symbol for "such that."  I saw it in logical notation for the definition of the limit of a function. M. Del Nero

Comment: This does not answer the question; it is merely a comment. I recommend that you revise over it and make improvements, or just delete it altogether.