# Is this notation standard?

Tags: notation

In a book I'm reading, "Sets: An introduction, by M.D.Potter", the symbol $\iota$ is used to mean "a definite", so that:

$\iota ! y(x\in y \iff \Phi(x))=\{x:\Phi(x)\}$

is read as $\{x:\Phi(x)\}$ is a definite unique $y$ such that $x\in y\iff \Phi(x)$, in other words "the unique $Y$ such that...".

Is this notation standard? or is there another symbol more often used?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this notation ($\iota$ seems to be used as the imaginary unit by some to avoid confusion with index $i$). Here $\iota!$ seems to introduce an universal property. Maybe you'll find some notation related to that term.

Comment: It's meant to mean "the unique"

Comment: Universal property is the same in fancier ("the object uniquely defined by $\ldots$ up to some isomorphy")

Comment: Possibly related? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852771/element-of-a-singleton-set-with-one-element-notation

Comment: It would be quite handy if it were more standard, because it sometimes replaces verbiage with tidy calculation. For example, if $f: A \to B$ is a surjection, and $g: A \to C$ is any function such that $f(x) = f(x')$ implies $g(x) = g(x')$, one can write $h(y) = \iota(g(f^{-1}(y))$ as an explicit formula for the unique function $h: B \to C$ such that $g = h \circ f$, and prove the latter equation by a tidy calculation involving the identity $\iota\{g(x)\} = g(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the standard (but not commonly used in textbooks of mathematical logic) symbol for [Definite descriptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description).

It was introduced by Bertrand Russell in his fundamental analysis of definite descriptions.

The reading of :

> $\iota x \ \phi(x)$

is simply :

> "**the** (unique) object $x$ such that $\phi(x)$", or "**the** (unique) object such that $\phi$ holds of it."

---

Thus : $\iota ! \ y \ (x \in y \Leftrightarrow \Phi(x))$ (but $!$ is redundant) means, as you say :

> "the unique $y$ such that $x \in y$ **iff** $\Phi(x)$ holds".

Comment: This notation appears more commonly in logic books about linguistics, though.