# Difference between $\iota x \in A. \ \phi(x) $ and $ \exists! x \in A . \phi(x) $?

Tags: logic, notation

**What's the difference between $\iota x \in A. \ \phi(x) $ and $ \exists! x \in A . \phi(x) $ ?**
( Where $ \phi(x) $ is some property of $ x $, and $  A $ is the universe of discourse ).

I'm talking about iota-notation as it appears in Bertrand Russell's  Principia Mathematica. I found these questions:
[Is this notation standard?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175663/is-this-notation-standard?rq=1)  ,  [Element of a Singleton (set with one element) notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852771/element-of-a-singleton-set-with-one-element-notation) . But  I still could not form-out a difference.
I know the statement $ \exists! x \in A . \phi(x) $ has a truth value.
However, does the " $ \iota x \in A. \ \phi(x) $  "  also have a truth value? do you have another analogy to what the iota quantifier might represent? and eventually, What's the difference between $ \iota $ and $ \exists!  $ quantifiers ?

Comment: The [iota symbol](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pm-notation/) is a term-forming operator: applied to a formula it outputs a *term* (a "name") meaning "the object" satisfying formula $\phi(x)$.

Comment: The [two are linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic):  $\iota x(\phi x)$ means "the unique $x$ such that $\phi(x)$" and thus we can use to write: $\psi ( \iota x(\phi x))$ that means:  "There is exactly one $\phi$  and it has the property $\psi$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\iota x \in A. \phi(x)$ is an object, not a proposition. So, if $A = \{1,2,3\}$, then $(\iota x \in A. x-1=1)$ is the number $2$.

On the other hand, $(\exists ! x \in A. x-1=1)$ is a true proposition.

Comment: If I'm writing $ \iota x \in A. \phi(x) $ , but such object $ x $ does not exist, then what can I say about $ x $? am I saying that such an object $x $ does not exist? can I also say that the object $ \iota x \in A. \phi(x) $  is ill-defined ( or does this work only in the context of talking about function domains )?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 You can either define it to be the empty set (or any fallback value you want) or call it undefined.

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Just think about our attitude towards 0/0.

Comment: And If I were asked to prove that the object $ \iota x \in A. \phi(x) $ exists. Then I'd have to prove the proposition $ \exists! x \in A . \phi(x) $ ?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Yes, but no one will phrase the problem that way.

Comment: You prove that $\exists x Px$ and this is fine, but if you want to rintroduce a "name" for an object, like e.g. the *empty set*, starting with the axiom: $\exists x \forall y \lnot (y \in x)$ you have first to prove that there is **only one** such set and only after that you can add to the theory a name for **the** (unique) set with no members.