# How to refer to the single element inside a unit set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The other similr questions/answers refer to advanced set theory notation or defining exclusive functions for this.
[I have answered here my own question with a middle ground solution.]

If sets were ordered, I could just do $s_1$ and get the first, also only element of the [unit set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) $s$. But they are not ordered. Is there a shorthand for that?

Related: how to extract an element according to a single-match criterion, like pertaining to another set?

Comment: What is a "unitary set"? Is that that a set of one element, i.e. a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics))?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/852771/81360)

Comment: By definition $\bigcup\{s\}=s$, though I suspect that only folks with some significant background in set theory will be familiar with the fact.

Comment: @lemontree I am a bit confused about needing a \phi to use the \iota thing.

Comment: The $\iota$ operator works on a statement, which is what $\phi$ stands for. In your case, the statement is "is an element of $s$". So: "the s" = $\iota x (x \in s)$. Probably readers familiar with the $\iota$ operator would also understand what you mean if you just write $\iota s$.

Comment: @lemontree Ok, I think I can use the shorter form of iota and explain in text at the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on parts of answers pointed by the comments, I think a good approach would be $[\{x\} \mapsto x](s)$.