# "Such that" symbol in logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So I am taking a logic course and I supposed to write down a couple of math statements using only mathematical logic symbols (the most basic ones but I can use disjunction and there exists). There are statements that require "such that" symbol in my opinion but I am pretty sure that is implied and I am not sure how to proceed . For example, Any two real numbers can divide some one number. I don't have the symbol for divide so I would have to work around that. What I would do is write for all $a,b$, there exists $x$ "such that" there exists $v_1,v_2$ "such that" $x=av_1$ and $x=bv_2$. Is this correct? Do I just ignore the such that and not write it when I use symbols?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309506/symbol-for-such-that-not-in-set

Comment: I sometimes encounter the notation "\" for s.t. (France)

Comment: Not a specific symbol. If formalized, the statement will be : $\forall a, b \ \exists x \ \exists v_1, v_2 \ (x=av_1 \land x=b v_2)$.

Comment: in semi-formal style, you can use ":" : forall $a,b$, there are $x, v_1, v_2 : x=av_1 \text { and } x=bv_2$.

Comment: such that is sometimes written with the symbol $\ni$.