# what does the inverse membership symbol means?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation

I know that the symbol $$ \in $$ stands for membership, but what does the symbol $$ \ni $$ stand for?

Because I know that in the set membership, one symbol stands for subset and the other ones for superset, but I cannot find the meaning of the other symbol

Thanks

Comment: It's just set membership written the other way round: $x \in X$ and $X \ni x$ mean the same thing.

Comment: Similar looking symbols are also used by some authors for "such that" - see [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/15455/23500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you want to write the set before the element. $A \ni x$ means exactly the same as $x \in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $a < b$ means the same thing as 
$b > a$ and $A \subset B$ means the same thing as 
$B \supset A$, one should not use the mirror image of $\in$ to mean "such that". It is a bad, confusing notation.